# How can I set the width of a QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidgetitem

Does it exist an equivalent function of `QTreeView.setColumnWidth()` for a `QTreeWidgetItem` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTreeWidget` inherits `QTreeView`, so you can use any function of `QTreeView` in a `QTreeWidget`.